# Running NGINXon Alibaba ECS is not reachable from the web

Tags: nginx, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

On Alibaba Cloud ECS instance I have NGINX working normally, I can ping it from my terminal but I can't access my site from the browser.

`nginx -t`

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

`service nginx status`

```
    ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-04 05:33:26 CST; 30min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1737 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 558 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 442 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1714 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1129)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1714 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─1738 nginx: worker process
```

when I point to my IP no response!
Where is the problem?

trying the suggested fixes gave the following
[respose from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WehNN.png)

Comment: forgot to mension that the nginx access.log is empty

Comment: Are you still having issue?

Comment: yes, not resolved

Comment: Okay. Have you configured your security group to allow port 80/443? If not, that's probably your issue. If you did, please share your nginx configurations, and also share your output of `netstat -ntpl`

Answer (score 1):

It's problem with your Firewall, try to allow port 80 / 443

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

And check the port is listen to 0.0.0.0 with

```
sudo netstat -tunalp | grep 80
sudo netstat -tunalp | grep 443
```

If it's not solve your problem with your internal security group on alibaba Console

- Go to ECS Console.
- in tab `Network & Security`, choose `Security Groups`

And make sure you have allow port 80 / 443 or if you want allow all port int security Groups [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k1t8.png)

Comment: followed all your valuable suggestions .. still no response on the browser. throws 504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

Comment: A 503 Service Unavailable Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that a server is temporarily unable to handle the request. This may be due to the server being overloaded or down for maintenance.

Comment: Check the firewall and security group please

Answer (score 0):

Did you selected Assign Public IP Address when you created ECS instance? It sounds to me like it does not have NatPublicIP address assigned during creation process of ECS.

Try to open ports:

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

Then try further to inspect ports:

```
sudo lsof -P -n -i :80 -i :443 | grep LISTEN
```

Check the status of local host:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1/nginx_status
```

Also try to restart server:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service nginx reload
```

If this does not help, try to go in debug mode and trace common errors.

If this does not help, go from the start with instance and nginx installation.

Hope this would give you idea about what step was missed.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. so far the ufw status is: allow From anywhere for Nginx HTTP , 80/tcp , 443/tcp . the ip is pingable from the terminal and can't be resolved from the browser , Nginx access.log is blank despite all what suggested. seems to be a kernel problem of my ubunto instance at AliCloud.. I'll delete it and run a fresh one.. thanks